# Net 6 Multiple Connection Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-string, .net-6.0

How to setup in Net 6 program.cs a multiple connection strings?
I want to work with Development, Staging, and Production environments, all of them pointing to different database servers.

NET 6. Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you saying you "want to work with Development, Staging, and Production environments" *simultaneously"? Because if not, you just have different appsettings files where `DefaultConnection` is defined accordingly

Comment: Sounds like the question is about different configuration files rather than multiple connection strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you could do.

First, create an appsettings.json like this:

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:5000"
      }
    }
  },
  "WillAppConfig": {
    "ActiveEnvironment": "Development",
    "DevDatabase": "server:123.123.123.123, user: will, pass:1234",
    "STGDatabase": "server:123.123.123.123, user: will, pass:1234",
    "ProdDatabase": "server:123.123.123.123, user: will, pass:1234"
  }
}
```

Then create a class somewhere in your project, that will serve to map the configuration to an object.

WillAppConfigurationMap.cs

```
public class WillAppConfigurationMap
{
    public string ActiveEnvironment { get; set; }
    public string DevDatabase { get; set; }
    public string STGDatabase { get; set; }
    public string ProdDatabase { get; set; }

}
```

Finally in your Program.cs, you could select the connection string to use depending on the value of ActiveEnvironment.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
WillAppConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("WillAppConfig").Get<WillAppConfigurationMap>();
var connectionString = "";
if (WillAppConfig.ActiveEnvironment == "Development")
{
     connectionString = WillAppConfig.DevDatabase
} 
else if (WillAppConfig.ActiveEnvironment == "Staging") 
{
    connectionString = WillAppConfig.STGDatabase
} 
else if (WillAppConfig.ActiveEnvironment == "Production") 
{
   connectionString = WillAppConfig.ProdDatabase
}

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{ 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
});
partial class Program
{
    public static WillAppConfigurationMap WillAppConfig { get; private set;}
}
```

You can remove the "Kestrel" section from the appsettings.json if you don't use it. You can use this approach to map any appsettings.json structure.

Then, you can access your configuration object from ANYWHERE in your app doing `Program.WillAppConfig`.

Comment: You can use different appsettings files for each environment: appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Staging.json etc. This takes advantage of the built-in support for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable

Answer (score 1):

Create multiple connection strings with different names in appsetting.json:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => {   
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(UseNameofConnectionString));
});
```

**Also you can create extension method which gives you required connectionString  when you call it.**

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple appsettings.json with the same DefaultConnection name but with different values across them, like `appsettings.Development.json` or `appsettings.Staging.json` or `appsettings.DevLocal.json` or `appsettings.Production.json` and so on. 
Then, you can configure them in your launchSettings.json adding multiple profiles, like for example:

```
  "profiles": {
    "Core": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7165;http://localhost:5206",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Local": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7165;http://localhost:5206",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "DevLocal"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

The value of the variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is going to fetch it from the configurations in its respective `appsettings.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.json`. The profile executed by default will be the one with the name of your project. To execute the new profile you just need to redirect it to it. This is how you do it from your cli:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile "Local"
```

In this case all settings will be taken from `appsettings.DevLocal.json` according to our Profile:Local configuration.